# xml processing in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, xml

I have an `xml` persisted in database something as follows:

```
<root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US">
    <dynamic-element name="fdemo-redirect-url" repeatable="false" dataType="string" indexType="" required="false" showLabel="true" type="text" width="25">
        <meta-data locale="en_US">
            <entry name="label"><![CDATA[fdemo-redirect-url]]></entry>
        </meta-data>
    </dynamic-element>
    <dynamic-element name="close_button" repeatable="false" dataType="document-library" indexType="" required="false" showLabel="true" type="ddm-documentlibrary" fieldNamespace="ddm">
        <meta-data locale="en_US">
            <entry name="label"><![CDATA[close_button]]></entry>
        </meta-data>
    </dynamic-element>


....
```

I need to write a query which should replace an hyphen in `name` attribute of `dynamic-element` tag whose `dataType` attribute is `html`. I ended up creating the following query. But this works only for one tag at a time. I do not want to loop it using a procedure. Is there a way to tweak this query in such a way that this works for multiple `dynamic-element` tags?

```
 UPDATE table_name 
      SET xsd = UpdateXML(
           xsd,
           '//dynamic-element[5]/@name', 
            CONCAT(
                'name="', 
                REPLACE(ExtractValue(xsd, '//dynamic-element[5]/@name'), '-', '_'), 
                '"')) 
      WHERE ExtractValue(xsd, '//dynamic-element[5]/@dataType') = 'html';
```

Here in this above query only 5th `dynamic-element` tag is handled for all the rows.